# "ansible_failed_task" & "ansible_failed_result" variables are undefined when rescue block is in a file

Tags: error-handling, ansible, ansible-2.x

The `ansible_failed_task` and `ansible_failed_result` variables give undefined error, when error handling is done using block-rescue in a file which is called from `main.yml` inside an Ansible role.

Folder structure:

```
roles/
  role-test/
    main.yml
    file_with_error_handling.yml
```

---

`main.yml`

```
- include file_with_error_handling.yml
```

---

`file_with_error_handling.yml`

```
- block:
    # some code with error.
  rescue:
    debug:
      msg: "Task- {{ ansible_failed_task }} failed with error {{ ansible_failed_result }}"
```

---

`test.yml`

```
- hosts: all
  become: yes 
  roles:
    - role-test
```

---

When `test.yml` is executed I get the below error:

> fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "the field 'args' has an invalid value, which appears to include a variable that is undefined. The error was: 'ansible_failed_result' is undefined\n\nThe error appears to have been in '/tmp/test/role-test/tasks/test_main.yml': line 32, column 6, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n#      msg: \"ansible_failed_task- {{ ansible_failed_task }}\"\n   - debug:\n     ^ here\n"}

And the same error I get for `ansible_failed_task` variable.

If I copy the code of `file_with_error_handling.yml` in `main.yml` and then execute it, it works fine. I get the values in `ansible_failed_result` and `ansible_failed_task`. The problem occurs only when I call it from a file.

Is there a way I can display the output of these variables?

Comment: Your supposed role folder structure is invalid for [a role](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_roles.html#roles). Your `main.yml` contains syntax error making it a list with a string (no `:`). You [cannot](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/14270) use `block` inside roles in Ansible yet. Your error refers to the `/tmp/test/role-test/tasks/test_main.yml` file which is not referenced anywhere in your playbook - there is no chance it is included because of the syntax error. This is a complete fabrication not a serious question.

Answer (score 3):

Seems it's broken again in 2.9:

```
]$ ansible --version && ansible-playbook broken.yml
ansible 2.9.0
  python version = 2.7.17 (default, Oct 21 2019, 17:20:57) [GCC 9.2.1 20190827 (Red Hat 9.2.1-1)]

PLAY [localhost] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Fail] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => changed=false 
  msg: test

TASK [debug] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  ansible_failed_task: VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround, try to create two files, one block.yml and a rescue.yml.

main.yml:

`- block:
  - name: Your block tasks
    include: block.yml
  rescue:
  - name: Rescue task in case of error in block
    include: rescue.yml`

block.yml:

`# some code with error.`

rescue.yml:

`debug:
  msg: "Task- {{ ansible_failed_task }} failed with error {{ ansible_failed_result }}"`

Comment: For me also `ansible_failed_result` and `ansible_failed_task` throwing undefined but it was because `with_items` loop, is there a way to make those variable available  for looping tasks ?

Comment: I have the same problem. It works well when there is no loop but it failed when loop exists.

Answer (score 0):

After testing this it seems there is a bug in versions of Ansible < v2.7 (tested in 2.6 and 2.5).

Indeed when using an `include/include_tasks/import_tasks:` with a file `included_tasks.yml` which contains a `block/rescue` tasks does **not** export the `ansible_failed_result` and `ansible_failed_task` variables.

`playbook.yml`

```
- hosts: local
  tasks:
    - include: included_tasks.yml
```

`included_tasks.yml`

```
- name: test block
  block:
    - name: Fail
      fail:
        msg: "test"
  rescue:
    - name: debug
      debug:
        var: ansible_failed_task
```

will return (in both 2.5 and 2.6):

```
> ansible --version && ansible-playbook playbook.yml
ansible 2.6.12                                                                                                               
  python version = 3.7.2 (default, Jan  3 2019, 02:55:40) [GCC 8.2.0] 

PLAY [localhost] ***************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *********************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Fail] ********************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "test"}

TASK [debug] *******************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "ansible_failed_task": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!"
}
```

Where as it works well in 2.7

```
> ansible --version && ansible-playbook playbook.yml
ansible 2.7.6           
  python version = 3.7.2 (default, Jan  3 2019, 02:55:40) [GCC 8.2.0]

PLAY [localhost] ***************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *********************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Fail] ********************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "test"}

TASK [debug] *******************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "ansible_failed_task": {
        "action": "fail",
        "any_errors_fatal": false,
        "args": {
            "msg": "test"
        },
...
```